# react-scripts Invalid Host header

Tags: reactjs

I created an app with react-create-app, I just dev it using npm start, that seems to do react-scripts start according to my package.json

Whenever I add a proxy to my package.json, I get this error message :

```
Invalid Host header
```

I get the idea, it's a security issue. What I don't get is how to fix it. I read several issues on github and QA here on the subject, the fix is easy enough, but I still don't get where to put it

in the end, I will add a whitelist of hosts. I think I saw it's possible.

but where do I put this config to start :

```
devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true
}
```

Comment: You would put that piece of code in your [webpack.config.js](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/). If you're using create-react-app, then you'll need to eject your app.

Comment: yes, I got that, but where am I supposed to put that webpack.config.js and what is the complete form of a classic webpack.config.js. I tried ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/webpack.config.js because there was a file named webpack.config.js but to no avail, I even tried to put syntax errors in it, npm start doesn't care, so I suppose it doesn't read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage it without changing stuff inside `node_modules` or by ejecting your project by using an npm package called [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired).

It basically has an option to override your default hardcoded settings for webpack that are inside a `create-react-app` boilerplate setup.

You put a `config-overrides.js` inside your root folder and change the scripts inside your `package.json` to match `react-app-rewired` instead of the `react-scripts`. This way you can override all the webpack config that's hard coded inside a react project by writing it down inside a `config-overrides.js` file.

The syntax is inside this [link](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). There's also an article about it which can be found [here](https://jaketrent.com/post/change-webpack-config-create-react-app-without-ejecting/).

Answer (score 14):

Another way to disable the host check would be to set the following environment variable: `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true`

That can be done by e.g. adding that line to `.env` file in the root of the project. Note that this is not a secure solution and should not be used in production.

Comment: This is a less invasive approach than the accepted answer, in case you just want to do dev testing from a second machine. Disabling the host check is not required in production because you should not use a dev build in production.

Comment: This is a great answer, especially if you have a .env.development file that you only use in development and not production

Comment: The .env is one possibility. Instead of creating such a file you can also just place `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` in front of your scripts command in your package.json, i.e. `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true react-scripts start`.

Answer (score 1):

I never found out where to put the webpack.config.js. It didn't work in the app root directory where I suppose it should go, it didn't do anything for me, I just ended up modifying where react-scripts invokes webpack-dev-server and then put the disableHostCheck to true directly before invoking.

Basically I changed the following line :

```
const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
  proxyConfig,
  urls.lanUrlForConfig
);
```

to :

```
var serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
  proxyConfig,
  urls.lanUrlForConfig
);
serverConfig.disableHostCheck = true;
```

that's really not good practice (modify the code and disableHostCheck), but now I know I can actually modify settings, I'll just go for a whitelist, may be one day I'll understand why it doesn't care about my webpack.config.js ^^

Comment: I am getting the same error. Can you please help where I can add this option

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `react-app-rewired`:

   ```
   npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
   ```
2. change `package.json` script to

   ```
   "start": "set PORT=80&&react-app-rewired start",
   ```
3. then add a file named `.env.development`, add this line:

   ```
   HOST=buzzbuzzenglish.com
   ```
4. then add `config-overrides.js` file (you can override some webpack settings there but don't have to - still, file have to be created)
5. finally you type `npm start`, then browser will open and navigate to buzzbuzzenglish.com and renders normally without the `Invalid Host Header` error.